# Like an Open Graph action

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have created an application with their associated Open Graph actions, already approved by Facebook.

When a user publishes an activity/action in their feed, it's possible to "like" it from there. But is it possible to like it from another page, ie. with the "Like" plugin? by somebody who is not an user of the application?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To like an action you need to have the user access_token or use the FB api for that

as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#like_action

This is how we do it:

```
 FB.api("[action id]/likes", "post", function(response){...});
```

Answer (score 0):

The like button works with a url, which is how facebook indexes pages.

Graph objects have urls which define them, and so you can of course put the url of a graph object as the url for a like button.
The graph actions don't have a url and so I don't think that you can attach a like button to an action.

I'm pretty sure that there's no way to like an action outside of facebook.

Comment: Just to clarify: It's possible to like actions outside of facebook, but I think that only if you installed the application linked to the action

Comment: How so? maybe I don't really understand what you want, or I'm just not aware of that, in which case I'll be happy to learn.